# Symfony3: Add 'multiple' option on grouping ChoiceType

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I would like to unable multiple selection with a grouping choice but I get the error:

**"Unable to transform value for property path "destinataires": Expected an array."**

The code:

```
    foreach ($manager->getRepository('CommonBundle:Compte')->findAll() as $value)
        $arrayCompte[$value->getPseudo()] = $value->getPseudo();

    foreach ($manager->getRepository('CommonBundle:Profil')->findAll() as $value)
        $arrayProfil[$value->getNom()] = $value->getNom();

    $arrayDestinataires['Profil'] = $arrayProfil;
    $arrayDestinataires['Compte'] = $arrayCompte;

    $ticketForm = $this->createFormBuilder($ticket)
    ->add('priorite',       ChoiceType::class, array(
        'multiple' => true, // working
        'choices' => array(
            'Faible' => 0,
            'Moyen' => 1,
            'Fort' => 2)))
    ->add('destinataires',  ChoiceType::class, array(
        'multiple' => true, //not working
        'choices' => $arrayDestinataires))
```

Note that without the "***'multiple' => true,***" it works.

Note that some options like "***'expanded' => true***", works.

EDIT:
The variable 'destinataires' is a ManyToMany relation. Apparently it's why I get an error.

I need to create a custom fromBuilder a overload this part and handle it on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that "destinataires" is a ManyToMany relation to a "Compte" object, and I wanted to add the "Profil" entity as shortcut for the user.
To handle the problem, I added an array variable to my entity to store the form result and use it.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the array $arrayDestinataires can't be rendered as a choice list. As far as I can see in your code this will be the final result of your array

```
$arrayDestinataires = array(
     'Profil' => array (.....),
     'Compte' => array (.....)
)
```

This structure can't be rendered as you want, because Profil and Compte could be the values but the corresponding array can't be transformed to string.

Hope this help you.

Comment: After some reseach I found out that's not the variable I send to the form that block, but the variable hosting.
'destinataires' is a relation ManyToMany. So know I need to find out how to handle this... ^^